# Slow regexprep with a very long string

Tags: matlab

I have simulation data in an ascii file with a lot of data points.  I'm trying to extract variable names and their values from it.  The below is an example of what the file format looks like:

```
*ESA
*COM on Tue Sep 27 15:23:02 2016
*COM C:\Users\vi813c\Documents\My Matlab\
*COM The pathname to the ESB file was: C:\Users\vi813c\Documents\My Matlab
Case013
*RTITLE

Run Date/Time = 20-SEP-2016 13:29:00
MSC.EASY5 time-history plot with     20001 data points
*EOD
*FLOAT
TIME FDLB(1) FSLB(1) FVLB(1) MXLB(1) \
MYLB(1) MZLB(1) FDLB(2) FSLB(2) FVLB(2) \
MXLB(2) MYLB(2) MZLB(2) FDLB(3) FSLB(3) \
FVLB(3) MXLB(3) MYLB(3) MZLB(3)
              0         884.439              -0         53645.8        -972.132 
        -311780         207.866         5403.68         1981.49          327781 
         258746   -1.74898E+006         84631.4         5384.25        -1308.47 
         326538        -97028.6   -1.74013E+006        -61858.1 
          0.002         882.616        0.008033         53661.1          -972.4 
        -311702         207.779         5400.42         1982.11          327784 
         258726   -1.74906E+006         84628.3         5381.01        -1308.44 
         326541        -97040.1   -1.74021E+006        -61858.8 
          0.004         876.819        0.031336         53705.6        -973.183 
        -311683         207.661         5391.19          1983.9          327795 
         258693   -1.74935E+006           84624         5371.85        -1309.63 
         326552        -97040.6   -1.74051E+006        -61858.8 
          0.006         869.491        0.061631         53763.3        -974.213 
        -311806         207.618         5377.45         1986.76          327813 
         258659   -1.74995E+006         84621.7          5358.2        -1312.04 
         326569        -97040.3    -1.7411E+006          -61861 
          0.008         861.718        0.095625         53828.1        -975.379 
        -312039         207.648         5360.82         1990.12          327834
```

A summary of data format characteristics is as follows:

1. Everything above "*FLOAT" is a header and I need to get rid of it
2. Stuff between "*FLOAT" and the first numeric value are the variable names
3. The variable names and the values are delimited by space(s) and '\'
4. The data are "lumped".  Each lump has values for the variables at a given simulation time step.  In the example above, there are 19 variables so that there are 19 numeric values in each lump
5. There can be multiple data sets; each preceded with "*FLOAT" and a variable name section

The following is how I am currently handling this data:

1. fileread the file --> one big string of characters
2. regexprep {'\s+,'\','\n'} with ',' --> comma delimited for strsplit
3. strfind "*FLOAT"
4. strsplit by ',' --> now becomes a cell
5. find the first numeric value by isnan(str2double(parse))
6. Then between the index from 2. and the index from 4 are the variable names and between the index from 4 and the next "*FLOAT" are the numeric data

This scheme is sort of working, but I can't stop thinking that there's gotta be a better way to do this.  For one, the step 1. is extremely slow.  I guess it's one big string for regexprep to work on with multiple things to replace.

How can I improve my script?

Comment: Why not use `textscan` or something that's made for parsing files rather than `regexp` because that's bound to be slow for a giant string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave this a shot with the string class which is new in 16b.

```
str = string(fileread('file.txt'));

fileNewline = [13 newline]; % This data has carriage returns

str = extractAfter(str, ['*FLOAT' fileNewline]);
str = erase(str, ['\' fileNewline]);
str = splitlines(str);

% Get the variable names
varNames = split(str(1))';

% Get the data
data = reshape(str(2:end), 4, [])';
data = strip(data);
data = join(data);
data = split(data);
data = double(data);
```

I'm not sure about how to load the file faster.

As mentioned in another comment, textscan could probably help. It might end up being the fastest solution. With the correct format specified and using the 'HeaderLines' option, I think you can make it work.